# GO language how to change value of object inside of pointer of map

Tags: go

How can I do it?

I have the list of objects, I want list all and change the name of object.
I have the list and I'm doing a while end send to another function, there I change the name, but the name doesn't save.

Any idea how can I do it?

https://play.golang.org/p/el3FtwC-3U

And if there is any book that I can read to learn more, please. 
Thank for helping me =D

Comment: You can to use `map[string]*Track` [play](https://play.golang.org/p/l8evRcRAme) or see answer of SirDarius

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20224478/dereferencing-a-map-index-in-golang might be relevant, as it explains that you cannot obtain a pointer to a value in a map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the range loop:

```
for _, track := range tracks {
    // send track to channel to change the name
    Working(&track, &c)
}
```

the `track` variable is actually a copy of the value contained in the map, because the assignement here works on the `Track` value type, and in Go, values are copied when assigned.

What you should do instead is use the key of your map and assign the values from within the loop.

```
for key := range tracks {
    t := tracks[key]
    // send track to channel to change the name
    Working(&t, &c)
    tracks[key] = t
}
```

See https://play.golang.org/p/9naDP3SfNh

Answer (score 0):

I didn't found how to get pointer to value in map so I think you have to use `map[string]*Track` instead and then work with pointers to `Track` structure in your `Working` function.

See https://play.golang.org/p/2XJTcKn1md

If you are trying modify tracks in parallel you are may be looking for something like this https://play.golang.org/p/1GhST34wId

Note missing buffer in chanel and `go Working` in `for range tracks`.