# Is golang map lookup by value or by reference?

Tags: dictionary, go, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

When I retrieve a struct from a map in Go, do I get a copy of the value?  Or do I get the actual value that's in the map?

For example, let's say I have a map from strings to structs:

```
type quality struct {
    goodness    int
    crunchiness int 
}
cookies := make(map[string]quality)
cookies["nutrageous"] = quality{goodness: 3, crunchiness: 10}
```

and I want to modify an entry.

Can I count on the returned value being the same as what's in the map?

```
c := cookies["nutrageous"]
c.goodness += 5
```

Or do I also have to go back and modify what's in the map?

```
c := cookies["nutrageous"]
c.goodness += 5
cookies["nutrageous"] = c
```

Comment: As there _are_ no references in Go the answer is obviously: By value.

Comment: I'm fine reopening this since you've accepted an answer (thought closing would prevent the continued downvotes). The underlying reason for the answers are the same however, so it's good to understand why your example couldn't possibly work when the value in the map isn't addressable in the first place.

Comment: So I'm right there with you on the answers being the same, and even that these questions stem from the same underlying lack of info.  But knowledge on SO needs to be indexed by question, and these are different indices -- having both questions even if they point to the same answer is still adding value to the site.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Indexing a map returns a copy of the map value. If the map value is a struct, then modifications to the returned struct value will not change the struct value in the map. You must assign the modified value back to the map.

If the value is a pointer to a struct, then modifications to the struct will be accessible through the pointer stored in the map.

Answer (score 0):

Just like the Cerise answer sais- it is not possible.
Instead, you could hold a pointer as a value in the map.

[Dereferencing a map index in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20224478/dereferencing-a-map-index-in-golang)